# Cannot find symbol. java compiler error

Tags: java

I started to learn java earlier this week (Monday) and now whilst just going through the excercises from http://programmingbydoing.com/
(Specific excercise I'm doing is http://programmingbydoing.com/a/a-little-quiz.html)

and now I've run into an error that I can't seem to fix.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Quiz
    {

        public static void main ( String[] args)
        {

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            String ready,answer3;
            int answer1,answer2, score;

            score = 0;

            System.out.println ( "Are you ready for a quis?(Y/N) ");
            ready = keyboard.next();

            if (ready == Y)
            {
                System.out.println ( "Great, let's get to it then!");
            }
            else if (ready == N)
            {
                System.out.println ( "Well since you did start this program of your own volition I assume you are ready and you're simply having a go at me.");
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println ( "Error, wrong input!");
            }

            System.out.println ();

            System.out.println ( "Q1) What is the capital of Australia?" );
            System.out.println ( "  1) Brisbane" );
            System.out.println ( "  2) Sydney" );
            System.out.println ( "  3) Canberra" );
            answer1 = keyboard.nextInt();

            if ( answer1 == 1)
            {
                System.out.println ( "Sorry, Canberra is the capital of Australia");
            }

            else if ( answer1 == 2)
            {
                System.out.println ( "Sorry, Canberra is the capital of Australia");
            }

            else if ( answer1 == 3)
            {
                System.out.println ( "Correct!");
                score = score+1;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println ( "Error, wrong input!");
            }

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println ( "Q2) Can you store the value 'cat' in a varible of the int type? ");
            System.out.println ( "  1) Yes" );
            System.out.println ( "  2) No" );
            answer2 = next.keyboardInt();


            System.out.println();

            if ( answer2 == 1)
            {
                System.out.println ( "Sorry, 'cat' is a string, ints can only store numbers." );
            }
            else if ( answer2 == 2)
            {
                System.out.println ( "That's right!" );
                score = score+1;
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println( "Error, wrong input");
            }

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println ( "Did vikings wear horned helmets in combat?(Y/N)");
        System.out.println ( "  1) Yes");
        System.out.println ( "  2) No" );
        answer3= keyboard.next();

        System.out.println ();

        if ( answer3 == Y )
        {
            System.out.print ( " That's wrong, the only times a viking would ever have..... nevermind let's proceed with the quiz");
        }

        else if ( answer3 == N )
        {
            System.out.println ( "Correct!");
            score = score+1;
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println ( "Error, wrong input!");
        }

        System.out.println ( "Overall, you got a total score of " + score + " out of 3 possible." );
        System.out.println ( "Thanks for playing");

    }

}
```

I appreciate any help anyone can provide!

Comment: Please provide the actual error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe define the symbols as strings

```
...
if (ready == "Y") // just Y without quotes is interpreted as a variable or keyword. You have to make it a string 
{
    System.out.println ( "Great, let's get to it then!");
}
else if (ready == "N")
{
    System.out.println ( "Well since you did start this program of your own volition I assume you are ready and you're simply having a go at me.");
}
...
```

Same for the following ones:

```
if ( answer3 == "Y" )
{
   System.out.print ( " That's wrong, the only times a viking would ever have..... nevermind let's proceed with the quiz");
}

else if ( answer3 == "N" )
{
  System.out.println ( "Correct!");
  score = score+1;
}
```

**UPDATE**: not explicitely part of the question, but it's a useful tip suggested by Sam: to compare strings, if you are interested in their content, use .equals(), for instance:

```
if (ready.equals("Y"))
```

**UPDATE 2**: another mistake suggested in the comments that will throw another kind of compilation error is

```
answer2 = next.keyboardInt();
```

that should be

```
answer2 = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Comment: also use `.equals(...)` for string comparison instead of `==`

Comment: also, it should be `keyboard.nextInt()` and not `next.keyboardInt()`

Comment: Additionally, if you flip your String comparison around and do something like "Y".equals(ready) instead of ready.equals("Y"), you can get the same logical result without having to worry about getting a NullPointerException if ready is null.

Answer (score 0):

ready == Y --> wrong
ready == "Y" or ready.equals("Y") --> correct

answer2 = next.keyboardInt(); --> wrong
answer2 = keyboard.nextInt(); --> correct